# Proof if $f: X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to Z$ then $ g \circ f$ is continuous at $a$

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $f: X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to Z$ are maps of metric spaces with metrics $d_X$, $d_Y$ and $d_Z$.

I am trying to prove that if $f$ is continuous at $a \in X$ and $g$ is continuous at $f(a)$ then $ g \circ f$ is continuous at $a$.

Proof:
Let $\epsilon > 0$

Since $g$ is continuous at $f(a)$ there exists a $\delta_1 > 0$ such that

$d_Z (g(y), g(f(a))) < \epsilon$ whenever

$d_Y (y, f(a)) < \delta_1$.

Since $f$ is continuous at $a$ there exists a $\delta_2 > 0$ such that

$d_Y(f(x), f(a)) < \delta_1$ whenever

$d_X (x,a) < \delta_2$ so

$d_Z (g(f(x)), g(f(a))) < \epsilon$.

In this proof, how do we know which metric to use and when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metric you use depends on which metric space you are in. For instance, in the statement

> $d_Z(g(y),g(f(a)))< \epsilon$ whenever $d_Y(y,f(a))<\delta_1$

you know that you need to use $d_Z$ for the first inequality because $g(y)$ and $g(f(a))$ are elements of $Z$ (as $g$ maps to $Z$). Similarly, the second inequality uses $d_Y$ since $y$ and $f(a)$ are elements of $Y$. (It's not explicitly stated that $y \in Y$, but it ought to be; similarly, it ought to be explicitly stated that $x \in X$ later in your proof).

Answer (score 0):

You use the metric that is relevant to the definition of continuity for the function, so those that correspond to the domain and codomain. In this instance we want to show that a composition is continuous, and it has domain $X$ and codomain $Z$. So to prove continuity we want to use the metrics corresponding to those spaces. In this instance we are looking for the $\delta>0$ for $d_X$ so that if $d_X(a,b)<\delta$ then $d_Z(g\circ f(a), g\circ f(b))<\epsilon$.

Since both $g$ and $f$ are continuous at $a$ and $f(a)$, we know that there is a $\delta_1$ corresponding to $d_X$ and $\delta_2$ corresponding to $d_Y$ as you mentioned. If we choose $\delta=min\{\delta_1 \delta_2 \}$ we can guarantee continuity.